# Delete similar record in table with custom condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard, sql-delete

I have a table in sql server and in my table is a field like `name`.
I need to delete records from my table with this condition.
All characters are similar except for the last character, and last character is "a" or "b"

For example table records are `name1a`,`name2a`,`name1b`,....
and need delete `name1a` and `name1b`

Comment: Is this is a wildcard question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to delete any rows that have duplicates in the table (matching all but the last character) rather than how to use a wildcard, here is how:

```
declare @names table (keycol int, namecol varchar(10))

insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (1, 'name1a')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (2, 'name1b')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (3, 'name2a')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (4, 'name2b')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (5, 'name3a')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (6, 'name4b')

;with dupenames as
(
    select LEFT(namecol,LEN(namecol)-1) as NameMinusOne
    from @names
    group by LEFT(namecol,LEN(namecol)-1)
    having count(*) > 1
)
delete from @names
from @names n
inner join dupenames dn on dn.NameMinusOne = LEFT(n.namecol,LEN(n.namecol)-1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
keycol      namecol
----------- ----------
5           name3a
6           name4b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about how to use wild cards to identify (and delete) certain rows?

In sql server the single character wildcard is '_' so if you want to remove rows that start 'name1' and have a single character suffix this kind of thing will work:

```
declare @names table (keycol int, namecol varchar(10))

insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (1, 'name1a')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (2, 'name1b')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (3, 'name2a')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (4, 'name2b')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (5, 'name3a')
insert into @names (keycol, namecol) values (6, 'name3b')

delete from @names where namecol like 'name1_'
```

If there are more characters after the 'name1' part you would use:

```
delete from @names where namecol like 'name1%'
```